# MaskedTextBox's decimal placeholder is not equal to NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, decimal, maskedtextbox

Assume we have a loсalizable C# WinForms application with a MaskedTextBox on it.
It has **Mask=990.099** (mask for decimal numbers, having decimal placeholder in it) and default **FormatProvider** (it is null by default).

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx) symbol **"."** is

> Decimal placeholder. The actual display character used will be the decimal symbol appropriate to the format provider, as determined by the control's FormatProvider property.

So I expect that it will be replaced at run time with culture-specific equivalent.

I wrote a method to set a culture for current thread the following way:

```
internal static class CultureLoader
{
    internal static void LoadEnglishCultureWithCustomDecimalSeparator()
    {
        var culture = new CultureInfo("en");
        culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "/";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;            
    }
}
```

And I use it before application start:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MaskedTextBoxMaskThreadCultureTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            CultureLoader.LoadEnglishCultureWithCustomDecimalSeparator();

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Inside my form I read actual value for **NumberDecimalSeparator** and try to find it in MaskedTextBox's mask:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        textBox2.Text = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        textBox3.Text = maskedTextBox1.Mask.IndexOf(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator).ToString();
        textBox4.Text = maskedTextBox1.Mask.IndexOf(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator).ToString();

        textBox5.Text = (103.98).ToString();
    }
}
```

But for some reason MaskedTextBox's mask is **"___.___"**, despite of **CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator** and **CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator** being **"/"** (and I expect exactly this symbol to be in my MaskedTextBox's mask):
[image]

So why MaskedTextBox doesn't change **"."** symbol (looks like it's default value for english culture) to **"/"** symbol for a decimal placeholder?

**UPDATE:**

1) Why do I care about this placeholder? Because in some scenarios i need to know index of decimal palceholder inside maskedtextbox mask. As I see now **maskedTextBox1.Mask.IndexOf(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Numbe‌​rFormat.NumberDecima‌​lSeparator)** is not woking - so what to do?

And because it is a technical requirement that decimal values should be represented exactly an they are in OS. **103.98.ToString()** for example will return **103/98**, not **103.98** as you can see on a screenshot of my form. So why maskedtextbox does it enother way?

2) I know that i can simply use **990\.099** for mask to make decimal placeholder culture-independent - but it's technical requirement to make it culture specific (for example as win calc app does):
[image]

**UPDATE2:**
Calling simply **Decimal.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text.Trim())** throws **FormatException**:

[image]

**P.S.** I've [**uploaded here**](https://yadi.sk/d/2qnA9R0EyeETU) a simple test application to run as-is.

**UPDATE3:**
I've tested some other cultures and summary is:

1. **"en"** - maskedtexbox's text is **"103.98"**, Decimal.Parse() throws FormatException.
2. **"fr"** - maskedtexbox's text is **"103,98"**, Decimal.Parse() throws FormatException.
3. **"es"** - maskedtexbox's text is **"103.98"**, Decimal.Parse() **parses correctly!**
4. **"ru"** - maskedtexbox's text is **"103,98"**, Decimal.Parse() throws FormatException.

So I'm finally confused - what is going on with this maskedtextbox?

Comment: It localizes the display of the MaskedTextBox, not the Mask property.  It is very unclear why you care.

Comment: @HansPassant I care for example because: 1) in some scenarios i need to know index of decimal palceholder inside maskedtextbox mask. as I see now  **maskedTextBox1.Mask.IndexOf(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)** is not woking - so what to do? 2) it is a technical requirement that decimal values should be represented exactly an they are in OS. **103.98.ToString()** for example will return **103/98**, not **103.98** in my form. So why maskedtextbox is representing it another way?

Comment: You are helping too much.  Mask is not localized so you never have to worry about finding it.  Just use "." instead of trying to make it culture-dependent.

Comment: @HansPassant It's technical requirement to make it culture specific (for example as win calc app does) - I've updated my question

Comment: @HansPassant And what do you mean by "Mask is not localized so you never have to worry about finding it"? According to MSDN artikle I've mentioned "The currency, thousandth, and decimal characters will be replaced at run time with their culture-specific equivalents." And It's working (if I change language to Russian for example mask will be **___,___**), but look's like only for language's default separator..

Comment: The Text property is localized.  It contains the data entered by the user at runtime.  He didn't actually type any comma or decimal point, they are added according to the Mask requirement and they'll match the current culture.  All you need to do is, say, Decimal.Parse() to convert it to a number.  It also uses the current culture so already does what your technical requirement says you need to do.  The Mask property is not localized, it tells MaskedTextBox how to produce its Text property value.  MaskedTextBox was designed to be easy to use and not require any localization-specific code.

Comment: @HansPassant **Decimal.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text.Trim())** throws FormatException - so your statement that _MaskedTextBox was designed to be easy to use and not require any localization-specific code_ is incorrect.. See UPDATE2 or run my sample application that I've attached